# Annotate seaborn distplot with log scale throws an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

```
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
ax1 = sns.distplot(titanic['fare'], kde=False, bins=15,)

# ax1.set_yscale('log')

for p in ax1.patches:
    ax1.annotate(
        s=f"{p.get_height():1.0f}",
        xy=(p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()), 
        xycoords='data',
        ha='center', 
        va='center', 
        fontsize=11, 
        color='black',
        xytext=(0,7), 
        textcoords='offset points',
    )
```

The above code plots the histogram for the `Fare` of the titanic dataset, where each bar is annotated with its value using `ax1.annotate`.
The trouble comes when I want to set the y scale to logc -- Uncomment the `set_yscale` line and run it; it throws an error saying:

> ValueError: Image size of 378x84035 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction.

Perhaps the xycoords parameter should be changed, but I'm not quite sure what to change it too.

I'm on Python 3.7.2, seaborn is version 0.9.0. Matplotlib version 3.0.2, and I'm using the Inline backend.

Comment: It works fine for me without any errors. seaborn version `'0.9.0'`

Comment: @Bazingaa Did you uncomment the `set_yscale` line? I'm on 0.9.0 as well.

Comment: Yes, I did. I got a logarithmic scale and the annotations are also on top of bars. I am using JuPyter notebook with inline display

Comment: Seaborn version is irrelevant. Matplotlib version and backend would be important information here.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest version 3.0.2, backend is "'module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline'"

Comment: Take the annotation out of the layout with Ann.set_inlayout(False) ?  Inline uses bbox_inches =tight and that can cause problems when elements are plotted out of the axes.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: matplotlib `'2.2.2'` and backend: `'module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline'`

Comment: @JodyKlymak Got it to work with this, but it's `ann = ax1.annotate(...); ann.set_in_layout(False)` instead. If you write up an answer, I will accept

Comment: I can reproduce this with matplotlib 3.0.2. But indeed it works without error with matplotlib 2.2.3. Of course the question is a bit, what is expected when placing an annotion at `y=0` on a logarithmic scale? Would we want to see the annotation at minus infinity? Or not?

Comment: We started including annotations in the layout calculation in 3.0, so the difference is expected.  But indeed the error is that y=0 is ill defined.  I think maybe we need logic in bbox_inches='tight' that bails in some sensible way and wants instead of errors.

Comment: @Troy  sorry for the bad syntax!

Comment: As long as the annotation is clipped by the axes, which should be the case by default (if `clip_on = True`), it should simply not be included in any layout, one could argue.

Comment: @JodyKlymak No worries, you pointed me in the right direction, the rest was trivial to figure out. (Thanks!) Regarding the y=0 remark, it's a good point. Though I agree with ImportanceOfBeingErnest that it should be clipped by the axes regardless.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Is a similar issue not present if one attempts to plot a scatter plot with a plot point with y=0 and yscale=log? (I mean, I'm just wondering why the annotations are handled differently)

Comment: I think a scatter point at y=0 is automatically excluded and not drawn. The extent of the collection does hence not include that point and therefore should not cause any trouble. (Autoscaling of scatters on log scale might still cause problems though.) Annotations need to be handled differently, because often enough you *want* them to be outside the axes. But as said, I think the `clip` property (or in consequence the `visible` attribute) is the best indication of whether they are to be included in the layout.That part seems to be missing in the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some annotations are placed at `y=0`. This will cause the position to be undefined on a logarithmic scale.
In a jupyter notebook with the inline backend the default option for showing figures is to run them through the `bbox_inches="tight"` option of `savefig`. This "tight" algrorithm is then unable to locate the labels and will extent the figure size to include them anyways.

The solution I would propose here is to set the `clip_on` option of the annotations to `True`. This will prevent annotations which are outside the axes to be visible. It thereby solves the problem of zero-placed annotations on the log scale.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
ax1 = sns.distplot(titanic['fare'], kde=False, bins=15,)

ax1.set_yscale('log')

for p in ax1.patches:
    ax1.annotate(
        s=f"{p.get_height():1.0f}",
        xy=(p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()), 
        xycoords='data',
        ha='center', 
        va='center', 
        fontsize=11, 
        color='black',
        xytext=(0,7), 
        textcoords='offset points',
        clip_on=True,                   # <---  important
    )

plt.savefig("outfig.png", bbox_inches="tight")
plt.show()
```

Comment: `clip_on` did it. Been searching for this answer for almost an hour now. Thanks!